# rotate in animation doesn't animate when the order of transform is not the same, why?

Tags: css, html, animation, rotation, frontend

Here's the demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGLGyY

the DIV doesn't rotate when the keyframe is:

```
@keyframes test1{
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0) scale(1, 1)  translate(0,0)
    } 
    100% {
        transform:  scale(2, 2) rotate(180deg)  translate(200px,200px) 
    }
}
```

when I change the keyframe to:

```
@keyframes test1{
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0) scale(1, 1)  translate(0,0)
    } 
    100% {
        transform:  rotate(360deg) scale(2, 2) translate(200px,200px) 
    }
}
```

It rotate again.

So what's the reason here?

I know the order may affect the transform.

Maybe because rotate(360deg) equals rotate(0); But when I change the order of transform it comes back again....

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform: none` for your first keyframe, and it will rotate.

Here it is in action:

```css
@keyframes test1{
 0% {
  transform: none;
 }   
 100% {
  transform:  scale(2, 2) rotate(360deg)  translate(200px,200px) 
 }
}

#test{
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  animation: test1 3s infinite
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```